# How to deal with async nature of firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im facing this issue due to the asynchronous nature of Firebase database in my quiz app.Question score contains the current user and its score .Ranking contains the users and their corresponding marks.Question score has the score stored in it but when i am updating the ranking database with the score ... The value of marks in Ranking object is being reset to zero.How should i approach this?

I've already tried using Ranking Callback to update the database but no luck.

```
public class RankingFragment extends Fragment {
    View myFragment;
    RecyclerView rankingList;
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Ranking, RankingViewHolder> adapter;

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference questionScore, rankingTbl;
    String k;
    int sum=0;

    public static RankingFragment newInstance() {
        RankingFragment rankingFragment = new RankingFragment();
        return rankingFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        questionScore = database.getReference("Question_Score");
        rankingTbl = database.getReference("Ranking");
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ranking, container, false);
        rankingList = (RecyclerView) myFragment.findViewById(R.id.rankingList);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rankingList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        rankingList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        updateScore(Common.currentUser.getUsername());
        return myFragment;

    }

    private void updateScore(final String username)
    {
        questionScore.orderByChild("user").equalTo(username).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    QuestionScore ques = data.getValue(QuestionScore.class);
                    sum+=Integer.parseInt(ques.getScore());
                }
                Ranking ranking = new Ranking(username, sum);
                rankingTbl.child(ranking.getUsername()).setValue(ranking);
                adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Ranking, RankingViewHolder>(
                        Ranking.class, R.layout.layout_ranking, RankingViewHolder.class, rankingTbl.orderByChild("marks")
                ) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(final RankingViewHolder viewHolder, Ranking model, int position) {
                        viewHolder.txt_name.setText(model.getUsername());
                        viewHolder.txt_score.setText(String.valueOf(model.getMarks()));

                    }
                };
                finish();


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void finish() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        rankingList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

The marks of the ranking database are storing 0 and thus the view holder is also populated with zero whereas it should store the score of the current user(stored in "sum+=Integer.parseInt(ques.getScore());"

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the value from `QuestionScore` to `sum` instead it should be like adding all the `QuestionScore` values

```
for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    QuestionScore ques = data.getValue(QuestionScore.class);
    sum+=Integer.parseInt(ques.getScore()); // <--- changed = to +=
}
```

Comment: I tried it but the result remains same ...sum stores the value zero.

Comment: Can you check wether you get correct values in `ques.getScore()`

Comment: for some reason the log message containing ques.getScore() value is not getting printed in console